# How to create a div in the same size as the contained image. Both should be responsive

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-images

I am creating a mobile e-mail template (means no javascript) which has to be responsive.

I want to place several images inline, which are scaled down as the screen gets narrower. I did this by using css table and table-cell, and let the image scale. No problem so far.

However, since images are often blocked by e-mail clients, I was requested to create a kind of placeholder in grey, showing the image "alt text" when the image is not loaded. I want this placeholder to be of the same size as the contained image, and to scale at narrower widths too.

I got quite far, as you can see in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ow7c5uLh/29/

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="placeholder">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/120/60/" alt="alt text" width="120" height="60" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="placeholder">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/120/60/" alt="alt text" width="120" height="60" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="placeholder">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/120/60/" alt="alt text" width="120" height="60" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}

.placeholder {
    max-width: 120px;
    max-height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #505050;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

However, there are two problems:

1. As the screen gets narrower and the images are scaled, the background-color pops out from under the image. The placeholder-div is scaling just as the image, but its height is calculated (by the browser) to be some 5px more then the image height. Where does that difference come from?
2. When the images are not loaded (try in the fiddle by just making the image URL invalid) then the placeholder-div's height collapses. How can I make it keep the correct height?

FYI: The actually used images won't always be of the same size, but I will know their dimensions and can calculate their aspect-ratio. I would write those values (like 120px) inline instead of in a separate css-file like in the example.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: block` to your CSS `img` rule to make it a block element instead of inline and you are good to go: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renevanderlende/ow7c5uLh/39/)

Change src="...." of one of them to src="" in the fiddle and you will see the the cell itself already scales.

By adding rule `img[alt] { font-size: 2vw; overflow: hidden }` to your CSS, the  html `alt="text"` will scale too. `overflow: hidden` chops excess text when `alt` is larger than your 120x60px.

(**note**: `[alt]` is called an 'attribute' in CSS, search for 'css custom attribute' should you want to learn to create your own.)

See [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renevanderlende/ow7c5uLh/41/)

I would advise against loosing the width and height rules of the `placeholder`, but you could change it to min-height/min-width to show at least that something 'is missing'. Or change to `max-width: 100%` and remove `max-height`, but this depends on your requirements. You will need to limit the size of an image somewhere up or down the line (for example giving the table a width in **px** and it's children a  (max-)width in **%** ).

Comment: Cool thanks, that fixes the grey background popping out from under the image when scaling. Do you have any idea how to deal with the second problem? When images are not loaded, then I'd like the placeholder div to remain the same height as it would be with the image in it (but scalable, so I can't give a fixed height)

Comment: change `src="...."` of one of them to `src=""` in the fiddle and you will see the cell already scales. And add rule `img[alt] {font-size: 2vw; overflow: hidden }` to your CSS. This makes the `alt="text"` scale too. `overflow: hidden` chops excess text when `alt` is larger than 120x60px.

Comment: Thanks again! This "font-size: 2vw" is a great idea, would never have though about those "vw". I'm not quite done yet, but this'll get me going I think!

Comment: `[alt]` is called an 'attribute' should you want to learn about that. I will edit my answer to refelct this comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove:

img {
   height: auto;
}    
problem-1 & 2: 

    img {
       max-width: 100%;
       max-height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Anand, thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately that doesn't work, because now the images don't scale properly. Their width gets squeezed, but the height stays the same when the screen gets narrower.

Comment: u have to use max-width: 100% also for img.

Comment: I have tried without image in the background it works.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/ow7c5uLh/36/](http://jsfiddle.net/ow7c5uLh/36/) I tried as you suggested, but the image doesn't scale, but gets squeezed.

Comment: It's in the updated JSFiddle which I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: remove:    .table {  width: 100% };